# суммирование элементов вложенного списка

Tags: python, list, матрицы

основная задача выглядит так:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/5263c6999e0f40dee200059d/train/python
мой код решения:

```
  def list_numbers(number):
    catalog = [number]
    if int(number) - 1 > 0:
        catalog.append(str(int(number) - 1))
    if int(number) + 1 < 10:
        catalog.append(str(int(number) + 1))
    if int(number) - 3 > 0:
        catalog.append(str(int(number) - 3))
    if int(number) + 3 < 10:
        catalog.append(str(int(number) + 3))
    if int(number) == 8:
        catalog.append('0')
    return catalog

def get_pins(observed):
    pin = [i for i in observed]
    catalog = []
    new_catalog = []
    for i in range(len(pin)):
        numbers = list_numbers(pin[i])
        catalog.append(numbers)
    
    return new_catalog
```

Я столкнулся со сложностью, я смог вывести список вариантов для каждой цифры, но не могу понять, как сделать их суммирование, если у нас могут меняться количество элементов в списке и вложенном списке.
Так что, мне для решения, надо решить эту под-задачу.

У меня есть список с вложенными списками

```
[['1', '2', '4'], ['5', '4', '6', '2', '8'], ['9', '8', '6']]
```

Мне надо вывести список в котором будет по 3 элемента всех возможных комбинаций.
Например, для списка:

```
[['1', '2', '4'], ['1', '2', '4']]
```

решением будет:

```
["11", "22", "44", "12", "21", "14", "41", "24", "42"]
```

длина вложенного списка может быть от 3 до 5 элементов.

*спасибо*

Comment: согласен с @MaxU, вы просто даете задачу. Вы даже не пытались её решить!..

Comment: @MaxU,  изменил вопрос, спасибо за комментарий

Comment: @FotonPC, изменил вопрос, спасибо за комментарий

Comment: @OvchinnikovKostyantin, я отозвал свой голос за закрытие и проголосовал за ваш вопрос ;)

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо. Я первый раз задаю вопрос, так что еще не сильно разбираюсь)

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. возможных вариантов не так много, то проще изначально составить словарь, где ключом будет число от 0 до 9 включительно (цифры), а значением будут все возможные варианты нажатия (в зависимости от условия).

```
dict_of = {0: [0, 8], 1: [1, 2, 4], 2: [1, 2, 3, 5], 3: [2, 3, 6], 4: [1, 4, 5, 7], 5: [2, 4, 5, 6, 8],
           6: [3, 5, 6, 9], 7: [4, 7, 8], 8: [0, 5, 7, 8, 9], 9: [6, 8, 9]}
```

В условии сказано, что на вход подается строка, поэтому сразу переведем наш словарь к строковым значениям. (на самом деле просто лень сразу было писать много кавычек ;) )

```
dict_2 = {str(i): list(map(str, j)) for i, j in dict_of.items()}
```

Далее сама функция

```
from itertools import product

def get_pins(number: str):
   list_of = [[key] + dict_2[key] for key in number]
   return list(set([''.join(i) for i in list(product(*list_of))]))


>>> get_pins('12')
>>> ['45', '42', '15', '23', '13', '12', '43', '41', '22', '21', '11', '25']
```

Что внутри?
Цикл по строке, в котором по ключу находятся списки значений + к ним добавляется сам ключ. В итоге получаем вложенный список со всеми значениями для каждого числа из строки.
Используем метод *product* из *itertools*,
прочитать можно [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) и возвращаем список уникальных значений.

Comment: Согласен с первым утверждением, только можно использовать типы либо `set()` (значения все равно уникальны), либо `tuple()`. И можно логику будет сменить. `set` из коробки имеет отличные методы для комбинаторики. Для `tuple` логика та же может быть